# Can I change the RPC timeout time? [PHP]

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, php

My wallet-rpc sometimes times out. It gets it done in the end, just not in the time that is required by the PHP `walletRPC` class. I was wondering if

a) The transfers sent get processed anyway, even if the RPC client times out
and
b) I can change the `timeout` time somewhere.

The problem would be if my code erros out, because of a timeout, and the transfer goes through, my code doesn't know it went through. And it acts as if it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

> My wallet-rpc sometimes times out.

It's your *client* that is timing out. Your "client" here is the 3rd party PHP library you are using.

Looking at the library, you should be able change things like the timeout via:

[get_client](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp/blob/master/docs/walletRPC.md#get_client)()->[setCurlOptions](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp/blob/a29052bcebd384f776d4e60a40c10fd435aabd96/src/jsonRPCClient.php#L57)(...)